# google maps addListener not working for input button click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

My `google.maps.event.addListener` is working fine for a textbox textchanged event, but I want to trigger it for any input button.

this is my script

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {

    var checkprice = document.getElementById('checkprice');
    google.maps.event.addListener(checkprice, 'onclick', function () {
        alert('button clicked');
    }
```

I have one similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10830149/issue-with-triggering-google-maps-on-button-click), but its solution has too many errors.

Comment: Instead of `addListener` can you try adding a `document.getElementById('checkprice').onclick = function () { alert('button clicked');};` statement?

Comment: yes , it is working , thanks

Comment: Cool Neeraj!. I have posted this as an answer. Can you please accept it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having an `addListener`, Can you try adding this,

```
document.getElementById('checkprice').onclick = function () 
{ 
    alert('button clicked');
};
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I've not tested, but it should be a DOM event:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(checkprice, 'click', function () {
    alert('button clicked');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery selector and click event is also a clean approach. You can try the following

```
$('#checkprice').click(function(){
    console.log('button clicked');
});
```

Below is the snippet demo.
You can also test and tweak with the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/y9a0h0je/) on jsfiddle.
Hope it helps.

```js
$('#checkprice').click(function() {
  alert('button clicked');
  console.log('button clicked');
  //check in console
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="checkprice" type="button" value="check price" />
```